# WPF Button Click Leading to Page

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I currently have 3 buttons in my main window. Button 1 I want to lead to Page1.xaml when clicked. Button 2 I want to lead to Page2.xaml and so forth. How do I go about this?

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
}



}
```

Comment: This might help you: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

Comment: Where do you want to display the pages?

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code will help:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      NavigationWindow window = new NavigationWindow();
      window.Source = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
      window.Show();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      NavigationWindow window = new NavigationWindow();
      window.Source = new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
      window.Show();
    }

    private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      NavigationWindow window = new NavigationWindow();
      window.Source = new Uri("Page3.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
      window.Show();
    }
}
}
```

You can optimize further by declaring `NavigationWindow`as a global instance and initializing in the constructor but that's up to you.